# Changing Default Mailto Hyperlink Font

Tags: hyperlink, email

Is there a way to change the default hyperlink font? I have the following code and I wish the email would be shown in Times New Roman Font. Can anyone please help?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{mailto:exmaple@example.com}{exmaple@example.com}\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can add arbitrary font commands to the second argument.

Comment: You may also check chapters 3.5 and 3.6 of the hyperref manual.

Comment: Problem solved?